# Scalable multi-parameter query

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

I have to do a SOQL query and I don't know how to do it in a scalable way.

In a no scalable way it would look like:

```
List<Items> items = new List<Items>();
items.add(new Item(1,1,2));
items.add(new Item(2,2,2));
items.add(new Item(3,3,3));
items.add(new Item(1,2,3));

List<ItemInDB> itemsInDB = new List<ItemInDB>();

for(Item aItem : items){

    itemsInDB.addAll ([
        Select Id, Name 
        from ItemInDB
        where ItemInDB.property1 =: aItem.prop1
        and ItemInDB.property2 =: aItem.prop2
        and ItemInDB.property3 =: aItem.prop3 ] );
}
```

The problem, is that there are no way to use it and get more than the salesforce sql querys limit.
Are there any way to do it in a efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As martin comments on one of the answers, some care is needed here to only return rows where all 3 values match. One way to do that is to add a formula field to the SObject that concatenates the 3 values in a distinct form and then query that:

```
List<Items> items = new List<Items>();
items.add(new Item(1,1,2));
items.add(new Item(2,2,2));
items.add(new Item(3,3,3));
items.add(new Item(1,2,3));

Set<String> keys = new Set<String>();
for (Items i : items) {
    // Same pattern here as formula field added to SObject
    keys.add(i.prop1 + ':' + i.prop2 + ':' + i.prop3);
}

List<ItemInDB> itemsInDB = [
        Select Id, Name 
        from ItemInDB
        where NewFormulaField in :keys
        ];
```

**PS**

Responding to the comment about matching varying numbers of properties, I think using `like` and wildcards would work:

```
        // Match 1st and 3rd and any value for 2nd
        keys.add(i.prop1 + ':' + '%' + ':' + i.prop3);
        ...
        where NewFormulaField like :keys
```

Comment: And are there any way to do it if there are a dynamical property  number and you don't know how many there are? may be you choose 1 in a query and 5 in another.

Comment: @DavidMarciel See the PS for one suggestion.

Comment: So you suggest a formula field using all the possible data and make a key using wildcards for the items you don't care about.
It solves the issue, but I am not sure about considering a best practise,  anyway you have helped a lot. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DavidMarciel Well "best" is always in a specific context - the idea that there is a single "best practice" is misleading. One important factor here is the number of rows involved: if the number of rows is large adding an index (possible here as the formula is deterministic) would make sense - see [Force.com Formula Fields, Indexes, and Performance Gotchas](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/03/force-com-formula-fields-indexes-and-performance-gotchas.html). You could post another question here asking for alternatives to this approach - I'd be interested in answers to that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to ask here but if you are worried about querying in a FOR loop, why can't you do like this?

```
List<Items> items = new List<Items>();
items.add(new Item(1,1,2));
items.add(new Item(2,2,2));
items.add(new Item(3,3,3));
items.add(new Item(1,2,3));
set<prop1Type> prope1Set = new set<prop1Type>();
set<prop2Type> prope2Set = new set<prop2Type>();
set<prop3Type> prope3Set = new set<prop3Type>();
for(Item aItem : items){
    prope1Set.add(aItem.prop1);
    prope2Set.add(aItem.prop2);
    prope3Set.add(aItem.prop3);
}

List<ItemInDB> itemsInDB = new List<ItemInDB>();

itemsInDB.addAll ([Select Id, Name 
        from ItemInDB
        where ItemInDB.property1 IN prope1Set
        and ItemInDB.property2 IN prope2Set
        and ItemInDB.property3 IN prope3Set]);
```

Comment: Note that with this query, there would be items with other combinations of properties, such as `2,1,2`, `1,1,3`, etc. that get returned, so it would not be exactly the same as the question.

Comment: I have thinking in many ways and it is one of them, I do not use it because, as @martin has said It would request for more than the ones you are searching for. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This may run into total length limits, but you could build a query dynamically if you cannot change your database definition:

```
List<Items> items = new List<Items>();
items.add(new Item(1,1,2));
items.add(new Item(2,2,2));
items.add(new Item(3,3,3));
items.add(new Item(1,2,3));

string whereFormat = '(ItemInDB.property1 = \'\'{0}\'\' and ' +
             'ItemInDB.property2 = \'\'{1}\'\' and ItemInDb.propery3 = \'\'{2}\'\')';

List<String> whereParts = new List<String>();

for(Item it : items)
{
    whereParts.add(String.Format(whereFormat, new List<String>{it.prop1, it.prop2, it.prop3}));
}

String query = 'select ID, Name from ItemInDb where ' + String.Join(whereParts, ' or ');

List<ItemInDb> itemsInDb = Database.Query(query);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have already choosen a different as response, but it also would fix the issue.